# Calling back history in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history

I am a huge fan of this magic in my `.inputrc` which allow me to quickly autocomplete a command with the up arrow key.

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\eOA": history-search-backward
"\eOB": history-search-forward
```

However very often, I have to ssh on a vanilla linux where I have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. I then usually became very unproductive because I don't know how to use this command.

It is time to question my workflow. Can I be more productive by using the native bash history reverse search than my `.inputrc` magic?

### Concrete use case

I would like to recall the last `python` line I have written. With my solution I do `pyt`+ <kbd>↑</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

With the reverse-i-search, if I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, `pyt`. I usually get any command containing `pyt`, not the last command starting with `python`.

More annoying, I usually realize I should use my history when I already typed let's say `pyth`. If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> I get:

```
(reverse-i-search)`': pyth
```

Which is very confusing because if I type `o` I suddenly get a WTF command I typed ages ago containing just a `o`.

I am totally sure I am not using the reverse-i-search the right way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using additional `CTRL` + `R` keystrokes to go beyond the first match?

In your example above, when you hit `pyth` you can then continue matching further back with additional `CTRL` + `R` presses.

Is that what you were looking for?

---

**Update: *Added example below, as requested.***

Example:  I want to match the older of these two similar commands.

```
$ python -m this
# ... snip...

$ python -c "import this"
# ... snip...
```

Now when you:

1. `CTRL` + `R`
2. Start typing `pyt`

At this point you have matched the latter of the two commands.  Not the one you want (in this example).

3. Hit `CTRL` + `R` one more time

At this point you will be matching the command you desire.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Does that example help?

Comment: @nowax,

If that is not what you were looking for, then maybe you could clarify and I'll see what I can do.  Best of luck.